# How do I have typescript have the type properly infered when using a generic initializer function?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a function that may take a parameter in the form of a callable like this:

```ts
type Initial<T> = T | PromiseLike<T> | (() => T) | (() => PromiseLike<T>)

const usePromise = <T>(initial: Initial<T>): T => {
  let result: unknown = null
  
  /* ... */
  
  return result as T
}
```

If the type of `initial` is something like `Promise<number>` or `PromiseLike<number>`, typescript correctly infers the type of `T` as `number`. However, if `initial` is of a function type like `() => PromiseLike<number>`, typescript infers `T` as `PromiseLike<number>`. For example:

```ts
// good:
const initial1 = new Promise<number>(() => null)
const result1 = usePromise(initial1)  // result1: number (OK)

// bad:
const initial2: () => PromiseLike<number> = () => new Promise(() => null)
const result2 = usePromise(initial2)  // result2: PromiseLike<number> (ERROR, should be number)
```

Note: obviously these promises would never resolve nor reject, but this question is purely about the type inference.

How do I get typescript to also correctly infer the type in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union presents multiple valid inference targets. The singular `T` type is allways valid and TypeScript propably does *not* put in the computation effort to see that `(() => PromiseLike<T>)` is also a valid target. We need to explicitly give an inference order to make the compiler examine more specific types like `(() => PromiseLike<T>)` first. I would suggest the use of overloads.

The overloads are resolved in order. The first overload is examined before the second one etc...

```
type Initial<T> = T | PromiseLike<T> | (() => T) | (() => PromiseLike<T>)

function usePromise<T>(initial: (() => PromiseLike<T>)): T
function usePromise<T>(initial: (() => T)): T
function usePromise<T>(initial: PromiseLike<T>): T
function usePromise<T>(initial: T): T
function usePromise<T>(initial: Initial<T>): T {
  let result: unknown = null
  
  /* ... */
  
  return result as T
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEkB2BLUyCGAbAPAFQHywC8susAPrAAoBOA9gLbIDO0AMsgNbR6GUAU-AJTFCuEQOGjq9Jqw7deQkADMArogDGaOolhrWtRix4F+yFGiwAuWIJFFCRuey6n8QobdzB1WnXoG0M4meAA0+OaWGJi29tLiXqS+GtrIuvqGsqG4EVGoMbYh8m5K3in+6YFZxqzhkRYFNqRJPn5pGUHFpnmNVrEI0VhlpLAA3sCwsJjQoLA00MxqmKC2GpyIdADueiSIy5iTsEcA9ABUsAB017BnJ0dHC6BqNHoLSyuw6MzJAL4gJxOsAA5nQ6AATazATS6ZhzPoxACMxFgiGgWxktR4+wYACNoDRIlJHKiDsoYYg4fNFstQMiSF1sqx8v1ESJYIDqR86bYcfiaHYAPIAaWUwE5uPQkOhsPhQ0wACY4g4nEzXIo+QTCCRiYQ0RjuvESftMJhybKubSFSjGViWTEFezOe8rUU1QpsWo8Vq7ABRABK-sF-rCsGYAAs6MtwbB8aTvTQhEA)